# How can I do AsyncLayoutInflater onCreate

Tags: java, android, performance, layout

The content part of the android application consisted of a lot of code structure. (3000 lines) I divided them into 3 viewstubs. I started 3 handler nested and then inflated the viewstubs.

But it did not accelerate again. it still opens very slowly. Now, while researching, I encountered asyntasklayoutinflater, but I think I couldn't do this job properly. No view appears in the content. // I deleted setContentView I also want to move my viewstubs into asynctask, but it is not static, how can I do this? Could you help? 
Thanks in advance!

```
   ViewStub viewStub1;
   ViewStub viewStub2;
   ViewStub viewStub3;
   View coachStub1;
   View coachStub2;
   View coachStub3;

   @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
       } else {
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       }


    new AsyncLayoutInflater(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onInflateFinished(@NonNull View view, int resid, @Nullable ViewGroup parent) {
               long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

               viewStub1 = view.findViewById(R.id.viewStub1);
               viewStub2 = view.findViewById(R.id.viewStub2);
               viewStub3 = view.findViewById(R.id.viewStub3);


               viewStub1.setLayoutResource(R.layout.viewstub1);
               coachStub1 = viewStub1.inflate();

               viewStub2.setLayoutResource(R.layout.viewstub2);
               coachStub2 = viewStub2.inflate();

               viewStub3.setLayoutResource(R.layout.viewstub3);
               coachStub3 = viewStub3.inflate();

               NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
               Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).cancelAll();
               initialize(view);
               new MainAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();

               new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {                    
                       VKIPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
                       vkipager.setAdapter(VKIPagerAdapter);
                       VKIPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       vkipager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
                    vkipager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
                       long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                       Log.d("Handler Displayed", "\t" + (finish - start));
                   }
               }, 100);


               menu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                     ///
                   }
               });



               inters_ad1 = new InterstitialAd(context);
               inters_ad2 = new InterstitialAd(context);


               new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       if (blink_settings && !MainActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
                           Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
                           anim.setDuration(500);
                           anim.setStartOffset(20);
                           anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
                           anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                           profile.startAnimation(anim);
                       }
                   }
               }, 8000);



           }
       });



  }
```

AsyncTask

```
  private static class MainAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
       private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityWeakReference;

       MainAsyncTask(MainActivity activity) {
           activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
           MainActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
           activity.sharedPreferencesKeys();
           activity.alertDialogClickListener();
           activity.changeListener();

           return "MainAsyncTask Worked!";
       }


       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           Log.d("MainAsyncTask", "" + s);
       }
   }
```

init method

```
private void initialize(View view) {
       loadframe = view.findViewById(R.id.loadframe);
       menu = view.findViewById(R.id.menu);
       bottombar = view.findViewById(R.id.bottombar);
       menu1 = view.findViewById(R.id.menu1);


       pageIndicator = coachStub1.findViewById(R.id.pageIndicator);
       vkisonuctw = coachStub1.findViewById(R.id.vkisonuctw);

       numberpicker = coachStub2.findViewById(R.id.numberpicker);
       radiogrouphareket = coachStub2.findViewById(R.id.radiogrouphareket);

       belkalcasonuctw = coachStub3.findViewById(R.id.belkalcasonuctw);
       belkalcasonuctwinfo = coachStub3.findViewById(R.id.belkalcasonuctwinfo);

// much more

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the view asynchronously，Call this method setcontentview (view) to set it to activity

like this:

```
new AsyncLayoutInflater(context).inflate(layout, null, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInflateFinished(@NonNull View view, int resid, @Nullable ViewGroup parent) {
//load view into activity
                activity.setContentView(view);
            }
        });
```